# TYPO3 extension: how to find certain TS setting

Tags: typo3

I found in typo3 admin side(/typo3), you can have two ways to set up TS,

1. you can set up through template->root, I think TS here will affect the whole site.
2. you can set up through template->certain page, it will only affect this page.

So my question is:

If I want to find where(which page) has TS setting such as : `code = LIST`, how could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try querying the database in phpMyAdmin or similar. The following looks in Template Setup:

```
SELECT pid, config, constants
FROM sys_template
WHERE config LIKE '%code = LIST%'
```

Replace `config` with `constants` to look in Template Constants. `pid` is the page ID.

Comment: Despite the fact that this solution also "works", I consider it the least convenient one. Not to mention you need another tool to do it although it can be done right inside the TYPO3 backend.

Comment: It doesn't cover settings in included templates from files. If you want to go this way, you have to run "grep -rl 'code = LIST' *" via the command line as well

Answer (score 2):

Use `Web` > `Template` module it has tools, you can for an example use `Template Analyzer` for the search

Comment: I clicked template->root->View the complete TS Listing, but did not find `code = LIST`, but in my template->demo(page)->set up, has below configuration: `plugin.tx_jcjob_pi1 {
 code = LIST
 type = latest
 viewID = 72
 searchID = 73
 view.crop = 400 | ... | 1
}`

Answer (score 0):

If it is not set in the TypoScript, it perhaps has been set in the plugin itself. Just check the plugin content element itself.

Answer (score 0):

In the Template module, go to the page where the setting is in effect.

Use the TSOB (Typo Script Object Browser) to search for "list":

[image]

This *must* show you all TS for this page that contains "list".

If you don't see the setting you can run a cmd/ctrl-F Search over the entire results.
You would have to search for "[code] = LIST".

Which will lead you to the following entry:

[image]

Hovering over the label will produce the above tooltip. Copy the line number.

Now change to the Template Analyzer. Here, you can click through all cascading templates and search for the line number:

[image]

This is definitely the line that sets that value.

From the "Template hierarchy" tree you will easily find the template that contains the setting.

[image]

Comment: For your case (as you know the name of the setting already), I don't think this is more useful that @biesior's answer, but it's the complete way to debug a TS issue